# The User ForiegnKey is now showing up as a field in django rest framework viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a backend for a web app using django rest framework. I have a profile model that has a user forieingkey referencing a django user. Everything is loading correctly except for one issue which is that the User field is not showing up in the django rest framework backend urls so that I can assign a user to the profile object i want to create... does anyone know why this is happening...

[image]

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    synapse = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='./profile_pics/',
        max_length=150
    )
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=150)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=150)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + ' profile'
```

viewset:

```
from users.models import Profile
from users.api.serializers.ProfileSerializer import ProfileSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
```

url:

```
from users.api.views.ProfileView import ProfileViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', ProfileViewSet, base_name='profile')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from users.models import Profile

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            'synapse',
            'bio',
            'profile_pic',
            'facebook',
            'twitter'
        )
        depth=2
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you set a **depth bigger that 0**, foreign key fields become not editable (if you send a POST with that field containing some value, DRF viewset would ignore it, and if the field is required, it will raise an exception).

One solution for that is to override `to_representation()` method of the serializer and set the depth and restore it to zero:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            'synapse',
            'bio',
            'profile_pic',
            'facebook',
            'twitter'
        )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.Meta.depth = 2
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        self.Meta.depth = 0

        return representation
```